# Adding jquery 'each' function to js function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]I have a datatable and there is a 'amount' column. I have a js function to seperate thousand and add currency mark to each amount in the table. However the function is not working on "each" row but only works on first row. When I google it, I understand that I need to add this function in a jquery each function. Could you help me about how to make this happen?

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return "₺"+x.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

    var val = parseInt($('#tutar').text());
    //Use the code in the answer above to replace the commas.
    val = numberWithCommas(val);
    $('#tutar').text(val);
```

```html
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="Piyasa" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th scope="col">No</th>
                          <th scope="col">Şirket</th>
                          <th scope="col">Alcaklı</th>
                          <th scope="col">Borçlanma Tarihi</th>
                          <th scope="col">Ödeme Tarihi</th>                          
                          <th scope="col">Tutar</th>
                          <th scope="col">Açıklama</th>
                          <th scope="col">Bilgi Güncelle</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right" >Toplam:</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                  <tbody>

                  
                  {% for musteri in piyasa  %}
                  

                      <tr>
                        


                          <th scope="row">{{musteri.id}}</th>
                          <td>{{musteri.sirket}}</td>
                          <td><a href="/piyasa/details/{{musteri.id}}">{{musteri.alici}}</a></td>
                          <td>{{musteri.borc_tarih}}</td>
                          <td>{{musteri.odeme_tarih}}</td>
                          <td id="tutar">{{musteri.tutar|floatformat:2}}</td>
                          <td>{{musteri.aciklama}}</td>                          
                          <td><a href="/piyasa/update/{{musteri.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Güncelle</a></td>
                      </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: Can you also paste the logic of foreach which you created.

Comment: To answer usefully we need to see the "*[mcve]*" code to reproduce your problem; in this case that's a representative sample of your data-table (enough for four or five rows of data) and JavaScript/jQuery that deals with this code. You don't necessarily need to use jQuery's `.each()`, but you do need to iterate over the elements you want to modify for presentation.

Comment: I am also looking for it. js foreach or jquery each functions works but I dont know how to write it.

Comment: `{% for musteri in piyasa  %}` - @BurakSilahtaroğlu: can you post the *rendered* HTML, we don't have access to your data.

Comment: You are using the same id in every row of a table. Id should be unique across your entire page.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#tutar").forEach((i)=> {i.innerText = numberWithCommas(i.innerText)});`

Comment: They'll be a duplicate for this:  To use .each: `$("#Piyasa tr td:nth-child(6)").each((i, e) => $(e).text(numberWithCommas($(e).text())))` but you don't need `.each` as `.text` has a loop option itself ->  `$("#Piyasa tr td:nth-child(6)").text((i, txt) => numberWithCommas(txt));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is not re-use the same id for multiple elements on the page, which you're doing inside your server-rendered loop building up table rows.

Instead use a class, and then use that class to target all the matching elements. In the example below I have used the class `format-number` to indicate any cell I want to run the formatting code on.

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return "₺" + x.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

$(".format-number").each(function(){
  const $this = $(this);
  const currentVal = parseFloat($this.text());
  $this.text( numberWithCommas(currentVal) );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="format-number">10101.23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="format-number">345678.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="format-number">123456789.45</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```